# ActiveRecord query fails in binding.pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, capybara, pry

I'm using `binding.pry` in a test environment but getting some very peculiar results:

```
[4] pry(#<RentalItem>)> self.charged_amounts
=> [#<ChargedAmount id: 1, type_of_amount:"rental", charge_id:1, rental_item_id:1>, #<ChargedAmount id: 2, ...>]

[5] pry(#<RentalItem>)> self.charged_amounts.where(type_of_amount:"rental")
=> []

[6] pry(#<RentalItem>)> self.charged_amounts.where(charge_id:1) 
=> []

[7] pry(#<RentalItem>)> self.charged_amounts.where(rental_item_id:1)
=> []
```

Trying to understand and get some ideas in terms of why the behavior above might be happening. I.e., give me a starting point to debug.

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling binding.pry in the app or in the test code? Is this a js:true test?  If in the app code it's possible the tests request has timed out so the test has continued, failed and database cleaner has removed the records - you can check that by calling `self.charged_amounts(true)` which will make rails reload the association rather than returning the cached records

Comment: this is in the test code, it's a js:true test, truncational strategy so the records should be there.

Comment: Add the test code around where you're putting the binding.pry to your question

Comment: Do the sql queries logged in test.log look normal?

Comment: @TomWalpole sorry I got confused, the binding.pry is in the app (model code) but it's triggered on a test. I guess what I'm wondering is, given that this is a same environment and just one query after another, is it really possible that records are removed immediately after I query and only with certain queries?

Comment: @FrederickCheung they look normal

Comment: @james Yes it's possible - the test code and app code run in different threads so depending on when a browser connection request times out, or capybara expectation wait times expire, etc. the test will continue, fail/end, and then database cleaner will clean the database.  The issue you're seeing is because when you pause the app code some associations (charged_amounts for instance) are already loaded into memory and cached -- accessing them again doesn't hit the database (unless you pass true to force a reload) - any futher query that isn't already cached hits the database which is now empty.

Comment: Long story short - if you want to check the database content at different points in your test put the binding.pry in your test code.

Comment: Ok thanks @TomWalpole

Answer (score -1):

That's because of how rails handles transactional fixtures. Basically, records are deleted between tests. You can read more about it here [Transactional Fixtures in Rails](http://anti-pattern.com/transactional-fixtures-in-rails)

Comment: not applicable in this instance, because these are all in the same instance of a pry environment. i.e., if the first query showed results, there's no reason the others should not. also i specifically have transactions turned off